# How to notify users for custom validation based on multiple properties

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, validationattribute

I'm trying to build a custom message validation that involves two or more attribute.

Here is a simplified version of my DTO:

```
public class FooDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    //more attributes...

    public bool IsValid 
    {
        get
        {                                
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name) && (this.Id == 0))
                return false; //You will have to specify at least one of the following: Id or Name
            if (this.Name == "Boo" && this.ID = 999)
                return false;  //Boo name and Id of 99 are forbidden 
            //More validation ifs.

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And my current controller implementation looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(FooDTO fooDTO)
{            
    if (!FooDTO.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(""); 
    // Rest of code        
}
```

This implementation does not acknowledge the user with the correspond message, like when both the `Id` and `Name` are missing, I want the user to be notified with something like "You will have to specify at least one of the following: Id or Name" validation error.

**Is there a way to use `ValidationAttribute` to achieve validation for two of more properties that involves complex validation?** (this is my [preferred](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) solution)

Or an elegant way to build the custom error message to be sent over in the `BadRequest(string message)` overload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use `IValidatableObject` to implement custom validation:

```
public class FooDTO : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    //more attributes...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && (Id == 0))
            yield return new ValidationResult("You will have to specify at least one of the following: Id or Name", new[] { "Id", "Name" });

        if (Name == "Boo" && Id == 999)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Boo name and Id of 99 are forbidden", new[] { "Id", "Name" });
    }
}
```

and in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(FooDTO fooDTO)
{            
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState); 

    // Rest of code        
}
```

For more information read [Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject)